# Azure Bot added to Microsoft Teams returning "The bot is not part of the conversation roster" error

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an Azure bot that we are using to build a message extension functionality in Microsoft Teams.

Users access it via the conversation feature in team channel.  It works by taking a search string entered by a user in the message extension, searching our database for matching entries, and once an entry is selected posting a message into a team channel linking to the resource.

It is working as expected in all environments except for Production, where we see the following behaviour:

- Some search strings return the expected ("nothing found") response
- But most search strings return a 502 error. The bot's log says "The bot is not part of the conversation roster"

We are sideloading the manifest for the bot and its associated tab app. As far as I can tell, there are no differences in bot or app setup between Production and the other apps we setup (QA, staging, etc)

I've checked the other SO posts and those on the Microsoft PowerUsers forum. They mostly say that the bot needs to be added to Teams in Azure, but this has been done. And it's working for all of our environments except for Production...

This is the manifest. It references the `eduMe` app already published in AppSource:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.11",
  "version": "1.1.3",
  "id": "28beac77-2765-4248-8a25-02779d7242ca",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
  "developer": {
    "name": "eduMe",
    "websiteUrl": "https://edume.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://edume.com",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://edume.com"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "resources/edume-hexamark.png",
    "outline": "resources/edume-outline-hexamark.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "eduMe Beta_test2",
    "full": "eduMe Beta_test2"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Giving the deskless workforce seamless access to relevant knowledge",
    "full": "Training your workforce doesn't need to be painful. No more clunky authoring tools and dated, desktop based learning. eduMe helps you deliver the training when and where your workforce need it."
  },
  "accentColor": "#F3F3FF",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "e9aa4df6-ed17-423f-bb7a-5cb1f6f090d7",
      "scopes": ["personal", "team", "groupchat"],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": true
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "29b96f25-2032-4fa4-8abd-5ac8f652699f",
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "searchQuery",
          "context": ["compose", "commandBox"],
          "description": "Command to search courses.",
          "title": "Search",
          "type": "query",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "searchQuery",
              "title": "Search Query",
              "description": "Your search query",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://edume-ms-teams.herokuapp.com/index.html#/config",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": ["team", "groupchat"]
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "index",
      "name": "Home",
      "contentUrl": "https://edume-ms-teams.herokuapp.com/index.html#/tab",
      "websiteUrl": "https://edume-ms-teams.herokuapp.com/index.html#/tab",
      "scopes": ["personal"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["identity", "messageTeamMembers"],
  "validDomains": [
    "localhost",
    "*.microsoftonline.com",
    "*.herokuapp.com",
    "*.botframework.com",
    "edume.com"
  ],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "29b96f25-2032-4fa4-8abd-5ac8f652699f",
    "resource": "api://edume-ms-teams.herokuapp.com/29b96f25-2032-4fa4-8abd-5ac8f652699f"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your manifest to test at our end?

Comment: Sure thing @Nivedipa-MSFT, I've added to the original question.

Comment: We have tested this with your manifest. Added app in Teams channel and mention messaging extension in conversation area and added test for search query. But at our end we are getting message like "You'll need to set up app". And set up app link is not working at our end.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UdXS.png

Comment: Thanks for testing... Can you send me the tenant ID for the tenant you're using to test it? I can then set you up (it's not yet self-serve)

Comment: Could you please share your mail ID so that I can send the required details?

Comment: Sure, it's james dot backhouse at edume dot com. Thanks!

Comment: Sent the tenant ID on mail.

Comment: As discussed on mail your issue is resolved. Could you please add the resolution here.

Comment: Turns out the issue was that there was a conflict between our new app and the existing one that had been published in the MS Teams store. The new bot was linked to the existing tab app - but when we sideloaded it into MS Teams then things got confused because it was referencing a tab app that didn't have the appropriate permissions.
Not sure if we could have solved it ourselves, but the MST submission team did!